# Any jQuery plugin that handles this kind of User Interface?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, user-interface

[image]

I just wondering if one plugin could handle all of this. 
Content Filtering, Sorting and Pagination launch Ajax request (then retrrieves DB information) that returns JSON object

The excellent DataTables plugin can manage this, but it's for table and since I don't want to encapsulate my contents in table rows, I don't want to use it. Besides I need something lighter.

Comment: Just FYI, "criteria" is already a plural (of "criterion"), so "criterias" makes no sense. "Crtierias" certainly doesn't exist. :)

Comment: Out of interest, what tool did you use to design this?

Comment: Tomalak: I'll remember that :)   
Cary: Balsamiq Mockups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building this from scratch with jQuery would probably not be very hard or timeconsuming. I could also recommend the [extJS](http://www.sencha.com/) framework for any UI buildng in javascript.
Take care!
/Marthin